# Question about an example of a conic bundle in a paper by Kollár

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, vector-bundles, conic-bundles

In the following beautiful paper by J. Kollár [Kollár 2016](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1605.04763.pdf),
in the example 20, he makes a construction of a particular conic bundle $X$ over $\mathbb{P}^2$.
He starts with a vector bundle $E=\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^2}(c) \oplus \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^2}(3) \oplus \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^2}$ and the line bundle $L=\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^2}$. Since $L \otimes Sym^2(E)$ is generated by global sections a general section gives rise to a smooth conic bundle $X \rightarrow \mathbb{P}^2$.

Then it comes the part which is not clear to me: he notes that $$\pi_{*}(\omega_X^{-1})=\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^2} \oplus \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^2}(3-c) \oplus \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^2}(-c)$$ and so for $c>3$ yields $h^0(\pi_{*}(\omega_X^{-1}))=1$. From this he deduces that $|-K_X|$ contains a unique K3 surface, obtained by intersecting $X$ with the divisor in $\mathbb{P}(E)$ corresponding to the $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^2}(3) \oplus \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^2}$ summand in $E$.

Is there a way to see more clearly why this divisor in $X$ is a K3 surface?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Adjunction formula: if $S\in \lvert -K_X\rvert$, $K_S\equiv (K_X+S)_{|S}\equiv 0$. Then use an exact sequence to show $h^1(\mathscr{O}_S)=0$.

Comment: @abx thank you very much! Could you elaborate a little more about which exact sequence gives $h^1(\mathcal{O}_S)=0$?

Comment: For instance $\ 0\rightarrow \mathscr{O}_X(-S)\rightarrow \mathscr{O}_X\rightarrow \mathscr{O}_S\rightarrow 0\,$. You have to prove that $H^2(\mathscr{O}_X(-S))=0$, which should not be too difficult on a projective bundle over $\mathbb{P}^2$.

Comment: The name is Kollár.